# Помогите составить регулягное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти все слова с текста (но в конце могут быть точки либо запятые).
Нужно корректно подсчитать количество букв в каждом слове.
Помогите составить регулярку которая будет искать слова без знака и со знаком в конце.

```
Du HAST MICH GEFRAGT
Du HAST MICH GEFRAGT und ich hab NICHTS GESAGT
WILLST du bis der Tod EUCH SCHEIDET
TREU ihr SEIN fur ALLE Tage
ХОРОШО ЖИВЁТ на СВЕТЕ
ВИННИ Пух,
От ТОГО ПОЁТ он эти ПЕСНИ ВСЛУХ.
```

Comment: `\b` - граница слова

Comment: Может подойдёт вариант сначала убрать из строки все знаки препинания, а после переделать строку в массив по разделителю (пробелу). Не шарю в джаве, но в шарпе этим занимается `split`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Du HAST MICH GEFRAGT Du HAST MICH GEFRAGT und ich hab NICHTS GESAGT WILLST du bis der Tod EUCH SCHEIDET TREU ihr SEIN fur ALLE Tage ХОРОШО ЖИВЁТ на СВЕТЕ ВИННИ Пух, От ТОГО ПОЁТ он эти ПЕСНИ ВСЛУХ.";
String[] words = s.split("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}]+");

for (String w : words) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

Но ваш вопрос и этот ответ не учитывают слова, содержащие дефис. Например: "как-то", "по-русски" и т.п. Этот код разделит их на два слова.

Answer (score 0):

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only)

\p{Punct}   Punctuation: One of !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~

\p{Space}   A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

Как посоветовали выше можно воспользоваться методом String.replace(), заменить знаки пунктуации на пробелы, а потом пройтись String.split() по пробелам.

Или воспользоваться паттерном и матчером Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+"), при совпадении уже тем же риплейсом заменять, то что вам необходимо.

Comment: И еще как говорят преподы, не забывать о мультилайне (?m), я правда сам этот парт еще не сделал